# Why is this INSERT adding an extra empty row?

Tags: java, mysql

When I insert data into my table,  it adds one empty(blank) row after each populated row. So the result looks like:

```
data1

data2

data3 
etc
```

The create table code is:

```
String title =
            "CREATE TABLE "+ db +".title ("+
                      "id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"+
                      "name varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,"+
                      "PRIMARY KEY (id))";
```

The insert looks like this:

```
String data = null;
data = in.readLine();
if(data!=null)
st.execute("INSERT INTO "+db+" .title (name) VALUES ('" + data + "')");
```

Can anyone tell me why this code adds an empty row ?

PS. For most other tables this does not happen. I am only having problems with 2 tables like. Also when I execute that query via phpmyadmin it doesn't create an empty row.

Comment: The execution of one INSERT statement will lead to one extra row. If you get blank rows it means you are calling the statement with empty data. Suggestion: add a `System.out.println(data);` before the if statement.

Comment: how to get rid of this ?

Comment: Not sure what you want to get rid of. If your input file (I assume it is from a file) contains blank lines then you could e.g. extend the if-statement to `if(data != null && data.length() > 0)`

Comment: @The Nail I read this data from textField from Client side and send it to the server, server adds it to the mysql database, I want to get rid of inserting that empty row because it ruins my other work. I have added that    System.out.println(data); and it prints me: sometext and in second row there is empty space

Comment: How do you know you have extra rows? Did you do a COUNT(*) before and after your insert? Or does the line you insert include a newline character at the end of the string and you are printing the string and seeing the newline character?

Comment: I see the rows count in phpmyadmin also I used COUNT(*) to make sure and it adds that empty row after I insert data, before I insert I dont have that row, I dont use new line character at the end of the string

Comment: I suspect that you're misinterpreting something.  INSERT shouldn't "stutter".

Comment: Look closely at your `if(data!=null)` statement.  Keep in mind that `data` can be non-null and still empty.  (And also keep in mind that readline can give you records that contain nothing but a carriage return.)

Comment: Are you sure there are empty rows? I mean, would you please execute `select * from my table` to see the generated primary keys? I'm suspect about your values, are they trimmed?

Comment: Are there possibly any triggers on the table?

Comment: HotLicks gonna look into it much closer and will let you know, <br/> @AmirPashazadeh: values are not trimmed I have executed command you have wrote me and it showed me 8 records for this: ![Valid XHTML](http://i44.tinypic.com/9ljz89.jpg).

Comment: Ok it has been solved, by very stupid mistake I didnt see I was sending empty data not null, thats why it was adding new empty rows in database, thanks for help guys :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "if(data!=null)" you need to have something that checks for all whitespace as well as nulls, look into using regex to find this (I believe "/s" will work though).